# VBA: Using Function in Matlab-generated Excel File

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I have a VBA function which I would like to use in my Excel file.

The Excel file is created via Matlab, and I would like to use the VBA function in a cell in one of the Excel sheets.

I could create a VBA function manually within the Excel file. However, since I am creating the Excel file through a program, I would like to save the VBA function as a file and then call it from Matlab.

Is there a way to use the VBA function in the Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

Save your VBA project as an Excel Add-In (File > Save as... "Excel Add-In (.xlam)"). Make sure that the Add-In is loaded in the Add-Ins dialog ([see here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-or-unload-add-in-programs-HP010096834.aspx)). This Add-In will be loaded with Excel and available for every workbook opened on this computer. However, if you share your workbooks with other users, the custom VBA functions from your Add-In will not be available to them.